# c encryption encountering same weird result every time

Tags: c, encryption

Forgive me if my code looks redundant for debugging.

I only type -ls as input. For first two encryption, it works fine, for the third time I type -ls, the encryption length is less than the actual length.

Just FYI, I use two fish and cfb, IV and key was generated just once.

The comments are showing the case of the third time:

```
        //buffer just read

        fprintf(stderr,"\nlen is %d\n",strlen(buffer));
        //Prints length 41

        int k = 0;
        int a = strlen(buffer);

         while(k<a) {

            mcrypt_generic (td, &buffer[k], 1);
            k+=1;

        }
        fprintf(stderr,"\nk is %d\n",k);
        //Prints length 41

        fprintf(stderr,"\nnew len is %d\n",strlen(buffer));
        //Prints length 36!!
        //And it's partial result
```

Why the third time it encrypts the same output only till the 36th of the characters, while the loop still looped 41 times?

The more weird thing is, after this third time problem, it encrypts -ls output for more than 10 times with no problem, and then has encrypted length of 5 for one time, then runs correctly again.

It's weird enough that no matter how many times I re-run the program, it happens at the third time with same wrong length.

I put it in the loop to debug, but simply `mcrypt_generic (td, &buffer, strlen(buffer));` has the same problem.

My guess is that it might because the decryption encountered an end of file and stopped. Another cause can be the buffer again, but it can't explain why it runs fine before and after.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like result of UB to me...

Comment: You want to run/test/debug your code using a memory-checker like Valgrind (http://valgrind.org)?

Comment: Any ways, we cannot answer this without seeing how `buffer` is defined/initialised.

Comment: Also you want to test the outcome of `mcrypt_generic()`.

Comment: `read(stdout,buffer, 512)` Are you really trying to read output stream?

Comment: Thanks, I added some lines to make the code more complete, and what's UB? Is there any other context for me to search?

Comment: try `read(stdout,buffer, 512)` --> `read(0,buffer, 512)`

Comment: *"an end of file symbol"* is a mythical thing. Also, try `STDOUT_FULENO`, and turn on the highest warning level of your compiler.

Comment: I'll change it to socket if you're happy, it just can read the output of -ls.

Comment: `strlen` returns the number of characters until the next `0` byte.  The `mcrypt_generic` might produce a zero byte partway through the output.  The length is `a`, not `strlen(buffer)` at that point.

Comment: `read()` just reads. It does not add a trailing `'\0'`. When treating what had been `read()` as a C-"string" make sure its `0`-terminated. Change `char buffer[512];` to be `char buffer[512] = "";` or `char buffer[512] = {0};`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart presumably you mean `STDOUT_FILENO`

Comment: Also `strlen()` returns `size_t` not `int`, so this `... "\nlen is %d\n",strlen(buffer));` should be `... "\nlen is %zu\n", strlen(buffer));`.

Comment: @M.M: *Reading* from Standard *Output* does not make sense, does it?

Comment: @alk there are several problems in the code (and probably several more in the bits of program not posted)

Comment: If it crashes at first loop I would have fixed it. I bet there're some deeper reasons to cause this problem. Thank you for the critisis. If I tell you the problem presists, can you switch your attentation and figure out the reason?

Comment: `while (read(stdout,buffer, 512)) > 0){` The parentheses don't add up here. Did you remove an assignment to a variable there to "simplify" your example code? Would that variable be of an unsigned type?

Comment: UB is Undefined Behavior, if you're still wondering about that

Comment: "must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. " I met all the requirements, I spent huge effort to isolate the problem, with some bad coding because I'm new to C, you guys are simply mean.

Comment: See, people are able to answer it, there's nothing to do with the coding flaw you're excited about. Anyone revert your vote or the hold for your justice instead of ego.

Comment: Now you learned to be silent. Good start for your personality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output generated by `mcrypt_generic()` is binary, and might include `'\0'` - this will happen for one in every 256 bytes produced on average. When your hit one of those `'\0'` your `strlen(buffer)` will tell you that your data returned is shorter than it actually is. You should not use `strlen` on data that includes `'\0'` as part of the data.

Comment: Thanks, if I want to send the encrypted data, is there a way to deal with it? A simple re-encryption may cause the other side not able to decrypt because they're out of sync.

Comment: If you want to send the data as text, you can do a base64 or hex encoding of the data.